# Is Local file sharing between devices possible without internet?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, android

Recently in an effort to radically change my life, I have cut off my internet.

I used to use my router for a number of things:

- Wireless printing locally
- locally accessing files from a Windows 11 machine through my Surface Pro
- locally accessing files from a main Windows 11 machine through Android 11 phone
- locally controlling my DSLR camera through Android 11 phone

As I understand it, this is generally achieved by connecting the two devices in question to the same WIFI router.

I was operating under this assumption when I cut off my internet but when the line was closed, everything stopped working.

So is an active internet connection a must to use the Windows File sharing feature?

I am now thinking this is due to the standard company issue WIFI router and that If I buy a professional networking router and configure it correctly things should work. Would this be another mistake on my part?

I really need access to local networking features without the internet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**My hardware:**

- Windows 11 64bit PC
- Windows 11 Surface Pro 6

Comment: How did you cut off your Internet?   So long as Network Cards are active and File / Print sharing and Network Discovery are ON you should be able to share files locally. So disable Internet on the WAN port of your router.

Comment: @john I cut of the internet by calling my ISP provider and terminating my contract with them I was informed the line would be disconnected on a certain day. On that day Everything stopped working, inlcuding file sharing between PCs and Android Device.

Comment: I have shared files between computers (not smartphones) without Internet (Internet Outage) and it worked fine.

Comment: @John Since you have confirmed for me that this is indeed possible then it must down to that standard company issue router. I will get a decent networking router tommorow and give that ago. Thanks allot for helping me John.

Comment: "*So is an active internet connection a must to use Windows File sharing feature?*" -- No, all you would need is a functioning Local Area Network (LAN).  In theory all you would need to connect multiple hosts to each other would be an Ethernet switch and/or WAP (wireless access point) (or just the WAP portion of a wireless-router unit).  If static IP addresses are cumbersome, then you need a server to provide DHCP.   You might also want a DNS server,  Such services could be provided by a Linux or Windows host, or more commonly by a "router" box.

Comment: I wonder if loosing Internet caused DNS to break - or if you just have a bad router?

Comment: @davidgo I think that is what happened as soon as I applied a static IP address to both of my machines things were back to working again. This was a great learning expierience and I will refer back to this thread when I want to improve things. Thanks allot to all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, filesharing does not require internet, in fact, it does not require a router (if the devices are on the same LAN/subnet). Just use your router as a switch/WLAN-AP and connect the sharing via IP addresses and everything should work fine.

Note: If you don't use the internet or more than one subnet you don't need a router. Getting a Switch and/or a WLAN-AP, will be much cheaper and more efficient.

Comment: Hey this worked for me, I was not familiar with the terms you used so I searched them up on my phone and eventually I found a way to give both my windows PCs a static IP address it still did not work until I turned of password protection under the advanced netword sharing window on control panel. No happy with lack of password but it will do with until I learn more about networking. Thanks allot for helping me

Comment: I would recommend to delete any "old" credentials you saved about the other device you want to connect to and to create a new shared folder and a new user that can access the folder. Usually redoing it step by step does the trick. Probable best to post a new question if you still have trouble.